# Why is my function not working properly in C?

Tags: c, string, function

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int proba(char a[][3], int y1, int x1){
    char s[1000];
    int br,broj;
    br=0;
    s[0]='\0';
    printf("%d\n", x1);
    while((y1!=3) && (x1!=3)){
      s[br]=a[y1][x1];
      printf("s= %s\n", s);
      y1=y1+1;
      x1=x1+1;
      br++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", s);
    s[0]='\0';
    return broj;
}


int main(void) {
    const char *needle;
    int konacno,n,i;
    konacno=0;
    n=3;
    char stack[3][3]={{'a','a','a'},{'b','b','b'},{'c','c','c'}};
    konacno=konacno+proba(stack, 0,0);
    konacno=konacno+proba(stack, 0,1);
    printf("%d", konacno);
    return 0;
}
```

In this code I have a 2d array of chars

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

and my program should create every possible string from this(horizontal, vertical, diagonal...), and I have written a function for that, but it doesn't work, so I reduced it to this code here, and it still doesn't work. The problem is that in the output from this I get

```
s= a
s= ab
s= abc
abc
s= abc
s= abc
abc
```

You can see that in the secund run of the procedure my *s* string is already *abc* even tho I have emptied the string twice with

```
s[0]='\0';
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong, I have written the exact code in pascal and it works like I want it, but here it doesn't...

Comment: Your program [does not compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1af2cbcb228fd1a). Also, all those warnings should be fixed. They may be related to your problem.

Comment: it doesn't compile because I didn't include the *count* function in the code, let me fix it

Comment: Now it's fixed, you can try running it, or if you want to see the whole code it's here https://ideone.com/kAFqFz

Comment: The proba function seems to do exactly what it's meant to; print the diagonal. What are you expecting it to do on the second run?

Comment: on the second run the s string should be *ab* , not *abc*, on the first run it will gather the chars from a[0][0] which is a, then a[1][1] which is b and a[2][2] which is c, on the second it should be a[0][1] which is a and a[1][2] which is b, and it should stop there, because x1 will become 3, and the reuirement for the while function is x1!=3

Answer (score 0):

In the C programming language, all strings need a null terminator at the end, which is specified as `'\0'`.  So in the loop, after adding a character to the string, you need to add the null terminator before printing the string.  The code should look like this

```
while((y1!=3) && (x1!=3)){
  s[br]=a[y1][x1];
  br++;
  s[br] = '\0';
  printf("s= %s\n", s);
  y1=y1+1;
  x1=x1+1;
}
```

Comment: thank you user3386109, this was very helpful! Too bad I can't upvote your answer yet, because of reputation